# What is the correct way to set up a VPN and then only allowing SSH from that VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn

What is the correct way to set up a VPN and then only allowing SSH from that VPN? I want to set this up to remove my SSH from the open internet and only allow access via a dedicated VPN connection, I'm just not 100% sure how to implement everything.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far?

Comment: So far I have verified that I need to remove SSH from the open internet, and need to only allow connections through said VPN. I'm not really 100% sure where to start, so I came here to get some advice in how to start said implementation. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I guess the good start would be chroot, if you want to ban all the other unix tools.

Comment: What sort of VPN?  OpenVPN?  IPSec?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

edit `sshd_config` located in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add this line at the bottom :

```
AllowUsers root@YOUR_VPN_IP
```

This allows you to log in to SSH as the **root** user from your IP.
Don't forget to restart `ssh service` :

```
service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Or set up iptables rules to allow inbound ssh only over VPN interface/IP and deny in other if's.